# Can't use AddHttpClient / IHttpClientBuilder in console app

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

I have some code from a web app that configures the http client to use a certificate. I relies on `IHttpClientBuilder` and `AddHttpClient`.

I'd like to use the same methods for testing in a console app, but I'm struggling to even get those types be available there.

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) says I can use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` in a console app (there it's used to initialize configuration), but even though this package is supposed to depend on `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, where above types and methods are supposed to live, the compiler tells me those types are unknown.

The console app is freshly created with .NET 6.0 and it's only package reference is `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting` at 6.0.1. Why does that not give me `IHttpClientBuilder`?

EDIT:

After

```
dotnet new console
dotnet add package Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
```

edit only `Program.cs` to

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

host.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
    services.AddHttpClient(); // not found
});
```

to find that `IHttpClientBuilder` and friends are still not there.

Comment: Look at the link below and see if helps. Hard to say exactly since you provided no code, but you probably didn't set up your DI container in a way that lets you use AddHttpClient or anything like that. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-usage

Comment: @ZachSexton I put the exact steps to reproduce the issue in the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.Http` package, in addition to `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

I had the exact same problem and the Microsoft documentation I read didn't mention this explicitly. It became obvious when I read this blog post: [Simple Example of Calling REST API with HttpClient in .NET 5.0 by Adam Storr](https://adamstorr.azurewebsites.net/blog/simple-example-of-calling-rest-api-with-httpclient-in-net5.0). In it, the author adds both packages.

On re-reviewing the documentation for the [`HttpClientFactoryServiceCollectionExtensions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), I noticed under the "Definition" header that the namespace is `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` but the assembly is `Microsoft.Extensions.Http.dll`.